# Running Camunda in clustered environment locks further deployment

Tags: docker, locking, openshift, camunda

I have a problem with my clustered Camunda environment. What I am trying is to run multiple Camunda instances on my Openshift Cluster. All of them are connected to a single oracle db instance.

My problem is, that the deployment of the first instance is working as expected. However as soon as I'm trying to scale the pods to e.x. 3 instances, at least one of them failes and remains stuck on the following output:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-07-15 14:04:39.503","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.camunda.bpm.engine.cmd","message":"ENGINE-13009 opening new command context","context":"default"}
14:01:00.741","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.PropertyEntity.lockDeploymentLockProperty","message":"==>  Preparing: SELECT VALUE_ FROM ACT_GE_PROPERTY WHERE NAME_ = 'deployment.lock' for update ","context":"default"}
{"timestamp":"2020-07-15 14:01:00.748","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.PropertyEntity.lockDeploymentLockProperty","message":"==> Parameters: ","context":"default"}
```

As the logs tell, it hast something to do with locking of process deployment. After further investigation I came across this article on the offical Camunda page:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/user-guide/process-engine/deployments/

And have seen these entries in the database:

[image]

**Problem: I do understand why the deployments are locked but the main problem is that the lock remains there forever and never gets released. I would appreciate any help!**

Answer (score 1):

Are you using autodeployment?! The mentioned article describes a weired situation where multiple nodes try to deploy the same resources. In my opinion this only should happen, when each node trys to autodeploy resources.

Using an explicit deployment (after nodes are started) should be executed on a single node.

KR, Joachim

Comment: Yes I'm using autodeployment. Why is this a problem?